# Why isn't my PageViewController's DataSource working correctly?

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, xcode8, ios10

I have created a simple storyboard with a PageView Controller.

I will flip between two other View Controllers.

My PageView Controller is a custom class `TutorialPageViewController`. I've also created a custom DataSource class.

In the DataSource class I expect the `pageViewController` methods to be called when I attempt to scroll. However this is not the case. I have break points at both methods and they are never called.

The first view controller, "Page the first" comes up correctly, but attempting to scroll around doesn't call the methods, so I can't use them yet (hence they return nil for now).

If I set the DataSource of my view controller to `self` and put the methods in there, they are called correctly. But I want to move the methods out to a separate class for better code management. So why doesn't it work?

I've tried

- Setting my DataSource class to be a `UIScrollViewDelegate` as well as a `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` and setting the view controller's `delegate` to be the DataSource
- The PageView's transition style is **Scroll**

[image: Storyboard overview]

```
class TutorialPageViewController : UIPageViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        reset()
    }

    func reset() {
        let dataSource = TutorialPageDataSource(storyBoard: storyboard!)
        let content = dataSource.firstContentViewController

        self.dataSource = dataSource

        self.setViewControllers([content], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class TutorialPageDataSource : NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    private var _storyboard: UIStoryboard

    var firstContentViewController: UIViewController
    var secondContentViewController: UIViewController

    init(storyBoard: UIStoryboard) {
        _storyboard = storyBoard
        firstContentViewController = _storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstContentViewController")
        secondContentViewController = _storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstContentViewController")
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // break point here never reached
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // break point here never reached
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIPageViewController dataSource` (and `delegate`) are weak.

You create your `TutorialPageDataSource` instance in the `reset` method, assign it to the weak `dataSource`, and then the `TutorialPageDataSource` instance goes out of scope and gets deallocated because there is no strong reference to it any more. So now the page view controller's `dataSource` becomes `nil`.

You need to keep a strong reference to the `TutorialPageDataSource` instance. Use an instance variable to keep the reference.

Comment: Thank you. I'll remember that one in future :)

Comment: Thanks...I was going crazy trying to figure out what was happening in my code.  I had the same problem of the controller not having a strong reference so it was getting deallocated.

Comment: how can we do this?